# laravel : else content is empty

Tags: laravel, if-statement, authentication

I want to the user doesn't answer twice only one time for the survey so

I used foreach , if , else 
but i got content for if but else is empty

controller :

```
public function test(Request $request, Survey $survey)
  {
    $surveys = Survey::orderBy('id','desc')->limit(1)->get();
    $surveys->load('user.questions.answers');
    return view('survey.table', compact('surveys'));
  }
```

view

```
@section('content')
@foreach ($surveys as $survey)
@foreach ($survey->questions as $item)
@foreach ($item->answers as $answer)

@if($answer->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
      <p>
        Hi there, there's no survey yet today, Come back later!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
@elseif(! $answer->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title"> Start taking Survey</span>
      <p>
        <span class="flow-text">{{ $survey->title }}</span> <br/>
      </p>
      <p>  
        {{ $survey->description }}
        <br/>Created by: <a href="">{{ $survey->user->name }}</a>
      </p>

      <div class="divider" style="margin:20px 0px;"></div>
      <div id ="circle">
        @if($survey->mook_type == 'image')
        <img class="fit-picture"
      src="{{$survey->mook_file}}"
      alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices" /><br>
        @elseif($survey->mook_type == 'video')
        <video class="responsive-video" controls>
        <source src="{{$survey->mook_file}}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        @else 
        <div class="video-wrapper">
            <div class="video-container">
              <iframe class="youtube-video" width="635" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{$survey->mook_file}}?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
          </div>

        @endif
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" value="Next">

      </div>
      <div id="Create" style="display:none">
          {!! Form::open(array('action'=>array('AnswerController@store', $survey->id))) !!}
          @forelse ($survey->questions as $key=>$question)
            <p class="flow-text">Question {{ $key+1 }} - {{ $question->title }}</p>
                @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="answer" type="text" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]">
                    <label for="answer">Answer</label>
                  </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'textarea')
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]"></textarea>
                    <label for="textarea1">Textarea</label>
                  </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'radio')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                    <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      <input name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" />
                      <label for="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                    </p>
                  @endforeach
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="something{{ $key }}" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]" />
                    <label for="something{{$key}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                  </p>
                  @endforeach
                @endif 
              <div class="divider" style="margin:10px 10px;"></div>
          @empty
            <span class='flow-text center-align'>Nothing to show</span>
          @endforelse
        {{ Form::submit('Submit Survey', array('class'=>'btn waves-effect waves-light')) }}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endif

@endforeach

@endforeach
@endforeach

@endsection
```

The resultat is an empty else content , is there any ideas to fix else or other ideas to prevent the users answer twice or maybe i have to use forelse and thanks

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking but use just `@else` instead of `@elseif(! $answer->user_id == Auth::user()->id)` and check if it returns what you need

Comment: its empty too :(